# underscore js find with nested json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nested, underscore.js

My nested json looks like (the depth is not defined. It can be any):

```
[{
"id":"1",
"label":"abc",
"children":[{
  "id":"2",
  "label":"xyz",
  "children":[{
    "id":"3",
    "label":"lmn",
    "children":[{...}]
  }]
},
.
.
.
{
"id":"4",
"label":"ghi",
"children":[{
  "id":"5",
  "label":"aws",
  "children":[{
    "id":"6",
    "label":"pqr",
    "children":[{...}]
  }]
}]
}]
```

Suppose now I have an 'id'. I want to get 'label' of that element. Using underscore how can I do this. I tried with `_find` but it returned `undefined`. Later on which I found that it returned result of the first level.

Comment: Please show your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner:

```
var label = _(json).find(function(item) { return item.id === "1"; }).label;
```

Or, if you intend to re-use this functionally:

```
function getItemById(id) {
    return _(json).find(function(item) { return item.id === id; });
}
// ...
var label = getItemById('1').label;
```

EDITED -- I missed a detail in the original question.

Try this:

```
function getItemById(array, id) {
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item = array[i];
        if (item.id === id) {
            return item;
        } else if (item.children.length) {
            var child = getItemById(item.children, id);
            if (child) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

var label = getItemById(json, '1').label;
```

Comment: I checked it just now. It checks only in the top most level. If my id is few level deep say 5th level then I get `undefined`.

Comment: Why wouldn't your `id` be in a consistent place?

Comment: Ah, I see... I missed some detail in your original post.  One moment...

Comment: Updated. That should get you what you're looking for.